# How to make an API call wait until the previous calls have been completed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an API in c# (MYAPI) which takes a request, and makes an API call to Unity (UNITYAPI) to perform some action.

The flow should be like this

Client -> MYAPI -> UnityAPI -> performs task -> response from UnityAPI to MYAPI -> response to client.

Now, A client can call MYAPI through different threads. MYAPI should wait for the previous MYAPI calls to complete (which in turn means that the UNITYAPI completed some action). MYAPI "CANNOT" send any request to UNITYAPI until the previous calls of MYAPI are responed back to the client.

Function in MYAPI to make api calls to UNITY API:

```cs
static async Task<string> PostURI(HttpContent c)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:4444");
            var response = string.Empty;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage result = null;

                try
                {
                    result = await client.PostAsync(uri, c);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Function in MYAPI which handles all the calls:

```cs
public void ProcessCalls(string operation)
        {

            HttpContent next = new StringContent(operation);

            while (isBlocked == true)
            {

            }

            isBlocked = true;

            var t = Task.Run(() => PostURI(next));
            t.Wait();

            isBlocked = false;

        }
```

Here, you can see the workaround I did. I just used a static variable isBlocked to make any call wait in an infinite while loop until any other operation is being done.

This works fine when I send 2 parallel calls to MYAPI. The second call waits for the first to complete, then proceeds to send call to UNITYAPI and waits. But when I send 3 calls in parallel, it breaks. The first call completes in unity but no response is received for any call. There must be an elegant way to do this.

So what i want is:
-The client should be able to send multiple requests to MYAPI.
-Each request should be made to wait till ALL the previous requests have sent a response back to client.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: The method which calls ProcessCalls:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("MyPostRoute")]
        public async void  MyPostRoute()
        {
            var request = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();

            // Doing some validations on the request
            if (request.isValid())
            {
                await helperobject.ProcessCalls(request);
                //helperobject is an object of the class which has the two functions mentioned above.
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Input was not in Correct format");
        }
```

Comment: Use a `semaphore` , and: try to make your code to use the `Task` return type. Maybe google some examples on `async` `await`

Comment: @Stefan I have used async but isnt my case where i need it to be not async? I need each call to the api to wait rather than execute in parallel.  And could you elaborate a little on using Task return type. What would i do with it / Can i use it somehow to block the API from executing other calls?

Comment: I'd recommend using [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8) and do not use `HttpClient` in a `using` statement : [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx). _" I just used a static variable isBlocked to make any call wait in an infinite while loop until any other operation is being done"_ - that is an Anti-Pattern. You can simply await the Semaphore (`WaitAsync`).

Comment: you should also block the semaphore, your "isBlocked" before entering the loop

Comment: @Draykoon Actually, no. With SemaphoreSlim, you can `await semaphore.WaitAsync();`.

Comment: use `lock`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) with a static object

Comment: @MohammadMirmostafa In an async context, that's a bad idea.

Comment: @Fildor Can you elaborate a little on the usage of semaphore. Its confusing me. As far as i understand, semaphores are used to make "threads" wait ( or something like that) . But i want the API call to be waiting here. Each API call will create a new semaphore which is pretty useless since we need to be able to wait based on the previous call and its response

Comment: I'll write up an example in a minute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Semaphore, you need to make it static, so all instances of that class use the same one. Then you can go like this:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim processCallsSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
// new SemaphoreSlim(1,1); => start with 1 count available and allow at max 1.

public async Task ProcessCalls(string operation)
{

    HttpContent next = new StringContent(operation);

    try
    {
        await processCallsSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        await PostURI(next);  // Assuming this is also an async API or can be made one.
    }
    finally
    {
        processCallsSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Brilliant code. The API calls are waiting for the other calls to complete. The only thing is I'm getting Ok response as soon as I send the request. I want the response only After PostURI function is completely finished. In PostURI, i am using 

await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

Is this the problem?

Comment: You need to await `ProcessCalls` in the caller. Do you?

Comment: I didnt get you.

Comment: The function that calls `ProcessCalls`, it needs to do `await ProcessCalls(operation);`. If you call it like `ProcessCalls(operation)` it will continue without waiting for `ProcessCalls` to finish.

Comment: I just changed it but no effect. Should I add that method into the question as well so that you can take a look?

Comment: Done :) Take a look

Comment: One glance: Don't `async void`. Make that `async Task`.

Comment: Oh my god you are a genius xD. It is working perfectly now. Just as a last question before i close this question, is it okay to not return anything while return type is Task?

Comment: That's what `Task` is for. If you wanted to return something, you'd need `Task<ReturnType>`.